# Using linq to determine if any element is ListA exists in ListB?

Tags: c#, linq, list

I'm trying to use PredicateBuilder to compose dynamic linq queries.  In my object, I have a list of "Statuses" and I have another list of statuses that I want to search for.

So I need to be able to look in my object.Status property (a list) and see if it contains any of the items in my query list.

I've been fiddling around with .Any() and .Contains() but can't seem to find the right syntax.

What am I doing wrong?  Below are some of the things I've tried, but none of them have the correct syntax.

```
myObject.Statuses.Contains(myStatusList);

myObject.Statuses.Any(myStatusList);

myObject.Statuses.Any(s => s == myStatusList);
```

Comment: If `Statuses` is a custom class, you could implement `IComparable` and tell your class what field or fields you want to use when comparing your data using built in methods like **Contains** or **Any**. Otherwise, you could just be comparing `base.ToString()` to `base.ToString()`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
got.Any(x => want.Contains(x))
```

On further reflection, however, I'd write a `ContainsAny` extension method, to make this more readable. The implementation would probably be the same (although `want.Intersect(got).Any()` would also work).

Comment: This is the first one I saw and it solved the problem.  Guess I was on the right track with Any and Contains, but it just didn't occur to me to combine them!  Thanks. =)

Answer (score 5):

Do you mean:

```
myObject.Statuses.Any(s => myStatusList.Contains(s));
```

? This would be equivalent too:

```
myStatusList.Any(s => myObject.Statuses.Contains(s));
```

Answer (score 1):

What about intersect http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336761.aspx#intersect1

```
  public void Linq50()
  {
       int[] numbersA = { 0, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9 };
       int[] numbersB = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 8 };

       var commonNumbers = numbersA.Intersect(numbersB);

       Console.WriteLine("Common numbers shared by both arrays:");
       foreach (var n in commonNumbers)
       {
           Console.WriteLine(n);
       }
   }
```